# Pairwise interaction matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to compute a pairwise matrix in R that counts the number of times individuals interact with other individuals (so the matrix will include N number of rows and columns corresponding to number of individuals). I have a dataframe that lists "actors" and "partners" in separate columns.

```r
nn <- data.frame(actors=c('DOL','DOL','DOL','DOL','DOL','NOR','NOR','NOR','NIN','JOJ'),partners=c('JOJ','JOJ','NOR','NOR','NIN','NIN','DOL','JOJ','NOR','NOR'))
```

The data are such that direction of the interaction is irrelevant, so each cell should count the number of times individual X acts on Y plus the number of times Y acts on X. Ideally, the data frame above should give a matrix that looks like this:

```
     DOL JOJ NOR NIN
DOL    0   2   3   1
JOJ    2   0   2   0
NOR    3   2   0   2
NIN    1   0   2   0
```

I started writing a loop to cycle through each individual in my dataset and to count his/her interactions both from actor->partner and partner->actor. I'm sure this would work, but is not ideal as the full dataset is quite large. Is there a better way?

---

Update:
Thanks for the responses! Both solutions work great! I'm posting my implementation of Josh's suggestion, which was very helpful.

```
x <- with(nn, table(actors, partners))
y <- t(x)

# unique individuals
u <- unique(c(rownames(x),colnames(x)))

m <- matrix(0,ncol=length(u),nrow=length(u),dimnames=list(u,u))

i1 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rownames(x),colnames(x)))
i2 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rownames(y),colnames(y)))

m[i1] <- x[i1]
m[i2] <- m[i2] + y[i2]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Base R's `table()` will get you what you're after:

```
x <- with(nn, table(actors, partners))
x + t(x)
#       partners
# actors DOL JOJ NIN NOR
#    DOL   0   2   1   3
#    JOJ   2   0   0   2
#    NIN   1   0   0   2
#    NOR   3   2   2   0
```

Comment: Neat, so this is essentially `with(nn,table(actors,partners) + table(partners,actors))` right?

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I noticed that this does not work if the transposed table doesn't share the same row and column names as the original, which might occur if certain interactions only appear in one direction. I got around this by creating a master matrix with all possible individuals, then using indices to subset just the rows and columns that matched before adding. I calculated indices like so (one for both the original and transposed tables) `i <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rownames(x),colnames(x)))`

Answer (score 6):

In the field of graph theory, what you are looking for is an *adjacency matrix*:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(nn), directed = FALSE)
get.adjacency(g)
#     DOL JOJ NOR NIN
# DOL   0   2   3   1
# JOJ   2   0   2   0
# NOR   3   2   0   2
# NIN   1   0   2   0
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much -- you saved me tons of time!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien how do you choose element from this matrix?