# How to use matrix to show relationship in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, relationship

I have a list x here:
[image]

I want to show the relationship between the elements like this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this in R?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why isn't the desired answer symmetric?

Comment: Thanks Dwin ! I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: I am also considering to write it as vector like :                   for John: c("Mary","Jack","Wendy")   What do you think of this?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13176741/1270695) and the suggested answers for something that seems very similar to your problem and let us know if that is along the same lines to what you might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, build a matrix of all pairs from your original list:

```
L <- list(c("John", "Mary", "Jack"), c("John", "Wendy"), c("Mary", "Wendy"))
x <- matrix(unlist(lapply(L, combn, 2, simplify = FALSE)), ncol = 2)
```

Then, use one of the methods shown here: [Pairwise interaction matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965618/pairwise-interaction-matrix-in-r/12965725#12965725). I like the one using graph theory tools :-)

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.edgelist(x, directed = FALSE)
get.adjacency(g)

#       John Jack Mary Wendy
# John     0    1    1     1
# Jack     1    0    1     0
# Mary     1    1    0     1
# Wendy    1    0    1     0
```

Comment: @flodel, +1 -- nice. I'll have to explore the igraph package some more. I [applied your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13183488/1270695) to another question from yesterday which was very similar to this one, but the data source was a `data.frame` that needed to be subsetted before using `lapply...combn...`.